# An instance of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: probability-inequalities

In the proof of Theorem 6.5 from the book by [Devroye et al.](http://www.szit.bme.hu/~gyorfi/pbook.pdf), how is the last inequality derived?
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left\{|\eta(X)-1/2|\mathbf{I}_{\{g(X)\ne g^*(X)\}}\right\} 
&\leq \mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbf{I}_{\{\eta(X)\ne1/2\}}|\eta(X)-\tilde\eta(X)|\mathbf{I}_{\{g(X)\ne g^*(X)\}}\right\}\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left\{|\eta(X)-\tilde\eta(X)|\mathbf{I}_{\{g(X)\ne g^*(X)\}}\mathbf{I}_{\{|\eta(X)-1/2|\leq\epsilon\}}\mathbf{I}_{\{\eta(X)\ne1/2\}}\right\}\\
&+ \mathbb{E}\left\{|\eta(X)-\tilde\eta(X)|\mathbf{I}_{\{g(X)\ne g^*(X)\}}\mathbf{I}_{\{|\eta(X)-1/2|>\epsilon\}}\right\}\\
&\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left\{(\tilde\eta(X) - \eta(X))^2\right\}}\\
&\times \Bigg(\sqrt{\mathbb{P}\left\{|\eta(X)-1/2|\leq\epsilon,\eta(X)\ne1/2\right\}}\\
&+\sqrt{\mathbb{P}\left\{g(X)\ne g^*(X),|\eta(X)-1/2|>\epsilon\right\}}\Bigg)
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that $\eta(x) = \mathbb{E}\{Y|X=x\}$ is the regression function, $\tilde\eta(x)$ is an approximation of $\eta(x)$, $g^*(x)$ is the Bayes classifier
$$ g^*(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if } \eta(x)\leq\dfrac{1}{2} \\
   1       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$
and finally, $g(x)$ is defined like $g^*(x)$ with $\tilde\eta(x)$ replacing $\eta(x)$. $\epsilon>0$ is fixed. $\mathbf{I}_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears as the standard method of proof that $(\mathbb{E}X)^2 \leq \mathbb{E}X^2$, so $\mathbb{E}X \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2}$.  That's how all those square roots get there in the last three lines.  C-S is hidden in there, admittedly, and you have to rearrange the $\mathbb{E}\dots \textbf{I}_{stuff}$ into probabilities, but that's the core of it.

Comment: [The Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) for C-S in probability theory seems to have what is used in the proof above: $(\mathbb{E}XY)^2\leq\mathbb{E}X^2\mathbb{E}Y^2$ or $\mathbb{E}XY\leq\sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}Y^2}$